# Ng-repeated directive template

Tags: angularjs

I am repeating objects in ng-repeat and sending them to directive, where template is loaded for each object. But when removing elements from collection, the repeated directive templates do not disappear from the view.

But if i repeat those same objects in div-s, then they change.

```
<div id="draggablePanelList" ui-sortable="sortableOptions">  
     <add-block2 ng-repeat="block in content.blocks" ></add-block2>
</div>

<div id="draggablePanelList" ui-sortable="sortableOptions">  
     <div ng-repeat="block in content.blocks" value="{{block.data.text}}">{{block.data.text}}</div>
</div>


//directive code

return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: link,
        replace: true,
        scope: true
    }

function link(scope, element, attrs) {

    $http.get(getTemplate(scope.block.name), {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(tplContent){  
         $('#draggablePanelList').append($compile(tplContent)(scope));
    });
}

function getTemplate(selectedtemplate) {
        var block= '';
        switch(selectedtemplate) {
                case "heading":
                    block= "someName.html";
                    break;
        return block;
    }
```

In add-block directive i compile the template in link function and append to $('draggablePanelList').

What i need for, is the template being removed when I delete object from content.blocks collection.
Any advice?

Comment: please share directive code

Comment: Don't use jQuery to modify the DOM. Just use the `template` or `templateUrl` attribute in the directive to specify which HTML should be generated by the directive.

Comment: Thanks, I just recently found a great solution with no jQuery.https://coderwall.com/p/onjxng/angular-directives-using-a-dynamic-template